# remove buffer list from command area - VIM 7.4

Tags: vimrc, statusline

I want to hide the buffer list from the command area - the list doesn't need to be always visible as it can be viewed with a command eg `:ls`.

The behavior would be similar to `set nobl` but global and without affecting `:bn` / `:bp`. So like `set noshowmode` for the buffer list. `:silent` looked promising but doesn't seem to persist when switching buffers. The buffer list is also suppressed for a few seconds after executing a `:` command.

What setting can be added to `.vimrc` to permanently hide the buffer list?

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with bufferlist in the command area. Can you share a screenshot? I believe you are using a plugin that you don't really need.

Comment: I'll be surprised if it was not related to a plugin. It looks like the consequence of a buf explorer plugin

Comment: Disabling .vimrc does indeed remove the behavior so this must be a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had accidentally copy-pasted an unwanted plugin into my `.vimrc`

`bling/vim-bufferline`

Removing this plugin fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `bling/vim-bufferline` installed, you can disable the echoing of the buffer line to command line, by setting:

`let g:bufferline_echo = 0`

in your .vimrc. This is set to 1 by default.

Also, to hide the file mode and ruler from command line, you can just set:

`set shortmess=F`

in your .vimrc.